# Quadratic Inequality in terms of variable $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the values of $a$ for which the inequality $x^2+ax+a^2+6a<0\;\forall x \in (1,2)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can Write Equation as $$x^2+ax+\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{3a^2}{4}+6a<0$$

So $$\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3a^2+24a}{4}<0$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: If $x$ is either $1$ or $2$ as mentioned in your question,we have the whole squared part $(x+\frac{a}{2})^2$ is always $>0$.So, for the whole thing to be less than $0$, the $\frac{3a^2+24a}{4}$ part must be $<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested in $f(x)=x^2+ax+a^2+6a<0\;\forall x \in (1,2)$

$$f(1)=1+a+a^2+6a \leq 0$$

That is $$a^2+7a+1\leq 0$$

$$ \frac{-7-\sqrt{45}}{2}\leq a \leq \frac{-7+\sqrt{45}}{2}$$

Also, we want, $$f(2)=4+2a+a^2+6a \leq 0$$

$$a^2+8a+4 \leq 0$$

$$\frac{-8-\sqrt{48}}{2} \leq a \leq \frac{-8+\sqrt{48}}{2}$$

Hence, overall, we need to take the intersection of the two constraint.$$ \frac{-7-\sqrt{45}}{2}\leq a \leq \frac{-8+\sqrt{48}}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh but answer given as $\displaystyle \frac{-7-\sqrt{45}}{2}\leq a \leq -4+2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake..... let me correct it now

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh  but I did not understand Why we put equality sign in $f(1),f(2),$ because here given $1<x<2.$

Comment: I am thinking of whether it is possible for $f(1)$ or $f(2)$ to take value $0$ while $f(x)<0 \forall x \in (1,2)$

Answer (score 1):

$$0>4x^2+4ax+4a^2+24a=(2x+a)^2+3a^2+24a$$

Now $1<x<2\iff2+a<2x+a<4+a$

$\implies(2x+a)^2<$min$\{(2+a)^2,(4+a)^2\}$

**Case**$\#1:$ If $(4+a)^2\ge(2+a)^2\iff a\ge-3,(2x+a)^2<(2+a)^2$

$$0>(2+a)^2+3a^2+24a=4(a^2+7a+1)$$

We need $a^2+7a+1<0$

As the roots of $a^2+7a+1=0$ are $\dfrac{-7\pm\sqrt{49-4}}2=\dfrac{-7\pm3\sqrt5}2$

$\implies$ either $a>\dfrac{-7+3\sqrt5}2$ or $a<\dfrac{-7-3\sqrt5}2$

But $a\ge-3$ and $\dfrac{-7-3\sqrt5}2<-3$

**Case**$\#2:$ What if $(4+a)^2<(2+a)^2\iff a<-3$

Left for you.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality as $$(2a+x+6)^2< (6-x)(3x+6)$$ 
The right hand side is positive for $1<x<2$, so we get
$$-\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}<2a+x+6<\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}$$
and
$$-x-6-\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}<2a<-x-6+\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}$$
$$\frac{-x-6-\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}}{2}<a<\frac{-x-6+\sqrt{(6-x)(3x+6)}}{2}$$
The maximum of the right hand side is $-4+2 \sqrt{3}$ (let $x=2$) and the minimum of the left side is $-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{2}$ (let $x=1$)
so $$-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{2}<a<-4+2 \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

$$\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3a^2+24a}{4}<0$$

Now observe that $\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$ is always non-negative. Hence the above inequality reduces to:
$$\frac{3a^2+24a}{4}<0$$
$$\implies 3a^2+24a<0$$
$$\implies 3a(a+8)<0$$

Now a product of two factors can be negative iff one of them is positive and one is negative.

So either $a<0$ and $a>-8$  $\implies -8<a<0$ 
 or $a>0$ and $a<-8$  $\implies a\in (-\infty,-8)\cap(0,\infty)$

Now check for $a=1$. You will see that the above inequality does not hold whereas it does if $a=-1$.

Hence the required values of $a$ belong to the interval $\color{red}{-8<a<0}$.

Comment: Thanks SchrodingersCat but answer given as $\displaystyle \frac{-7-\sqrt{45}}{2}\leq a \leq -4+2\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

If $x$ is either $1$ or $2$ as mentioned in your question,we have the whole squared part $(x+\frac{a}{2})$ is always $>0$.So, for the whole thing to be less than $0$, the $\frac{3a^2+24a}{4}$ part must be $<0$